# Setting observer for a search suggestion dropdown

Tags: ember.js

I have an `input` search field and a twitter bootstrap dropdown underneath.

When the users types something in the `input` field (Ember `input` helper with value `customerSearchQuery`) there is a computed property in the controller that returns an array of altenatives that will populate the dropdown. I also have a method in the view that handles the dropdown, which will set an `active` class on the first element in the array that will later be used for navigating the dropdown with the keyboard when the `input` field is focused. The view hierarchy looks like this, they all use the same controller:

```
Care.NavbarView = Ember.View.extend({
    controller: Care.NavbarController.create(),
    templateName: 'navbar',
    CustomerSearchView: Ember.View.extend({
        selectedSearchMatch: 'ean',
        searchStateLoading: false,
        searchStateSuccess: false,
        searchStateFail: false,
        SearchMatchesView: Ember.View.extend({
            tagName: 'li',
            classNameBindings: ['isActive:active'],
            setSelectedSearchMatchToFirst: function() {
                console.log(this.get('controller').get('customerSearchQuery'))
            }.observes('controller.customerSearchQuery'),
            isActive: function() {
                return this.get('content.value') === this.get('parentView.selectedSearchMatch')
            }.property('content', 'parentView.selectedSearchMatch')
        })
    })
})
```

The problem is that the observer (`setSelectedSearchMatchToFirst`) doesn't always fire, only when the computed property does (which uses `this.get('customerSearchQuery')` and then returns results based on that value). Why is that, and how do I get it to fire every time the `customerSearchQuery` input field is changed?

Comment: Would you mind setting up a jsbin?  you can start at emberjs.jsbin.com